# why is my vscode doing a line break or deleting code while saving?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code

Im having an issue with vscode and reactjs. Ever since i started coding with react js every time i save my file, vs code produces a line break on .js files and deletes my code if i save a css file. I don´t know what might be producing this. I just know that for the css files i have to be constantly refreshing the window. Any hint? This only happens in my reactjs projects, in other languages the editor works fine. So basically suppose i have a reactjs component and i save my file, automatically the file is saved but vscode makes a line breake in the very top of my code every time i save it.

Comment: In vscode settings, can you tell us what is the value for  `editor.formatOnSave`  and `editor.defaultFormatter` ?

Comment: @BaptisteF. how do i reach that? I have Format on save is a checkbox which  is not clicked. Format on save mode is in the option 'file'. editor.formatOnSave: true